# Pulling out a data from Row (onrowselection) LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, onrowselection

I am new in programming and salesforce.
I have a little problem i have code with datatable and I want pull out my data from row with help of `onrowselection`.

Exacly I what to see in consol log or toast message a name of company when I will click on button show.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<lightning-datatable 
                    if:true={showCompanies} 
                    hide-checkbox-column 
                    onrowselection={handleRowAction}
                    data={companys.data} 
                    columns={columns} 
                    key-field="Name"></lightning-datatable>
```

**JS**

```
import { wire, LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import getAllCompanys from '@salesforce/apex/StockMarketSharesWrapper.getAllCompanys';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';

export default class stockMarketShares extends LightningElement {
  @wire(getAllCompanys, {}) companys;

  columns = [{
    
    type: 'button',
    initialWidth: 50,
    typeAttributes: {
        
        label: 'Show',
        variant: 'base',
    }
},{ label: 'Name', fieldName: 'Name' }, { label: 'Ticker', fieldName: 'Ticker' }]

    
    handleRowAction(event) {
        
    }
      

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made it. Maybe will help to somebody.

```
handleRowAction(event) {
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(event.detail.action));
        if(event.detail.action.name==='first_button') {
            //console.log('clicked FIRST button');
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(event.detail.row));
            //console.log(event.detail.row.Name)


            const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Company Name',
                message: event.detail.row.Name,
                variant: this.variant,
            });
            this.dispatchEvent(evt);

        } else if (event.detail.action.name==='second_button') {
            console.log('clicked SECOND button');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Glad you persisted and were able to obtain a solution! +1 for posting your own answer to potentially help future readers.